# Editar duas tabelas em simultâneo numa view "edit"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho duas tabelas: `Pessoa` e `Catequizando`, com uma relação 1:1 e quero fazer um "Get" aos dados das duas tabelas, ambos os "id´s" são iguais, então fiz o

```
Catequizando catequizando = db.Catequizando.Find(id);
Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoa.Find(id);
```

Não sei como fazer o `return view` das 2 tabelas.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Catequizando catequizando = db.Catequizando.Find(id);
            Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoa.Find(id);
            if (catequizando == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.CatequizandoID = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "PessoaID", "Nome", catequizando.CatequizandoID);
            return View(catequizando);
        }
```

Comment: Infelizmente não respondeu a minha questão, eu consigo fazer o @create entre 2 modelos na view, utilizando um viewmodel, mas não consigo fazer "get" aos dados de 2 tabelas no edit.

Comment: Acho que saquei, seu problema está nos .Find(id) ? porque na pergunta você colocou "não sei como fazer o return view das 2 tabelas." ?

Comment: @Brunno Por que apagou sua resposta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que eu fugi do que ele estava perguntando

Comment: @Brunno Não fugiu não. Este é o caminho certo. Faltam algumas coisas apenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe intermediaria (view model), onde você terá dois atributos, um do tipo Catequizando e Pessoa exemplo:

```
public class CadastroViewModel
{
    public Catequizando catequizando { get; set; }        
    public Pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Agora passe essa classe no model da sua view, e depois receba o mesmo no seu controller. Para acessar os atributos na view basta fazer o processo normal:

```
@model caminho.CadastroViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.catequizando.SEUATRIBUTO)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.pessoa.SEUATRIBUTO)
```

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Catequizando catequizando = db.Catequizando.Find(id);
    Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoa.Find(id);

    CadastroViewModel cadastro = new CadastroViewModel();
    cadastro.catequizando = catequizando;
    cadastro.pessoa = pessoa;

    if (catequizando == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.CatequizandoID = new SelectList(db.Pessoa, "PessoaID", "Nome", catequizando.CatequizandoID);
    return View(cadastro);
}
```

Comment: O meu problema é não na view, mas sim no controller, fazer return dos dados que vou editar de 2 tabelas.

Comment: atualizei o código acima de um olhada!

Comment: Sim é mesmo essa a minha resposta, mas não consigo fazer o get ao campos das tabelas.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Tens a resposta certa.